# Cannot run byobu because [root] does not own [/home/ubuntu]

Tags: permissions, ubuntu-18.04, byobu

I can't able to switch into byobu session. Its shows above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long I came to know that, We should give the permission to that user for /home/ubuntu path.

```
sudo chown -R $USER /home/ubuntu
```